# BackgroundService in .NET Core web application start listening to websocket

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, websocket

I'm trying to listen to messages coming from a websocket connection. I want this connection to be alive for the lifetime of the application.

My first instinct was to use a BackgroundService but I'm not sure if this is the way to go as the documentation states "Avoid performing long, blocking initialization work in ExecuteAsync" or am I misinterpreting this statement?

To further clarify: the OpenWebSocketConnectionAsync method eventually calls ReceiveAsync on a ClientWebSocket which is blocking until a message arrives.

If a BackgroundService might not be the way to go in this instance then what should I use instead?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
 public class WebsocketBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        public KNXServiceFactory _knxServiceFactory { get; }

        public WebsocketBackgroundService(KNXServiceFactory knxServiceFactory)
        {
            _knxServiceFactory = knxServiceFactory;
        }

        private const int RetryDelayInSeconds = 10;

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using var dbContext = KrzContextFactory.GetContext<StoroDashboardDbContext>(true);

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var credentials = dbContext.Branches.AsNoTracking().ToList();
                try
                {
                    if (!credentials.Any())
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No credentials available.");
                    }

                    foreach (var credential in credentials)
                    {
                        await _knxServiceFactory.Create(credential.Store365SiteCode, credential.Url, credential.Username, credential.Password).
                            OpenWebSocketConnectionAsync(stoppingToken);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    KrzApp.Log.Exception(ex);

                    // Wait for a period of time before attempting to restart the service
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(RetryDelayInSeconds), stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not need a background server.  You can just use OpenWebSocketConnectionAsync().  The background service would be needed if you connection method way not Async.  You should be able to register an async event to capture the receive data.

Comment: @jdweng where would I call the OpenWebSocketConnectionAsync then? During the start of my application?

Comment: After you setup the dbContext since the service would be writing to the database.

Answer (score 0):

> am I misinterpreting this statement?

Yes. It specifically states "blocking", and by that it means "synchronous". Since your code is asynchronous, it's not an issue.

The reason to avoid blocking code in initialization is because the host starts all its background services one at a time, and if one blocks synchronously instead of asynchronously, it will delay the startup of the app as a whole. Many developers (myself included) just always wrap our background worker code in a `Task.Run` to ensure this will never be an issue.

More info is on my blog: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html